# NavHost's composable() function calling itself again on executing navController.navigate() in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

> here is my simple code :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        SqueezeMyBrainTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            navGraph(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
  > NavGraph
```

```
@Composable
       fun navGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
        Log.e("Dhaval", "navGraph:", )

          NavHost(navController = navController,
          startDestination = "one"){

          Log.e("Dhaval", "navGraph: INNER BLOCK", )

          composable("one"){
          Log.e("Dhaval", "navGraph: ONE", )
              genericFun(name = "one") {
              
              navController.navigate("two"){
                  restoreState = true
              }
          }
      }
         composable("two"){
              Log.e("Dhaval", "navGraph: TWO", )
              genericFun(name = "two") {
                  navController.navigate("three")
              }
          }
      composable("three"){
          Log.e("Dhaval", "navGraph: THREE", )
          genericFun(name = "three") {
              navController.navigate("one")
          }
      }
  }
}
```

```
 @Composable
 fun genericFun(
 name : String,
 click : () -> Unit
) 
{
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ){
        Button(onClick = click) {
            Text(text = "${name} Click Me!!")
        }
    }
}
```

> When i click on button it trigger the lambda function and in lambda i called navigate() to navigate to another composable. Because of this navigate() the composable call itself first and then execute

```
    navController.navigate()
```

line.

I tried everything and refer every possible workaround but coulnt found any solution.
please help me.

Comment: that's how it works it will call the composable block again and execute functions inside it again, if you want to initialize a view model that is shared in more than one screen, inside a composable block then make sure that it's a sharedViewModel so you would get the same instance of it in all of your screens. https://youtu.be/FIEnIBq7Ups

Comment: so what problem you are facing?

Comment: i was observing flow in one of the composable so if the navHost's composable executes oftenly then it will affect my UI because of multiple calls. so what should i do in this ??